# jQuery autocomplete text seperated with comma not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

code: **search_json.php**

```
<?php
    function get_data()
    {
        $ci =& get_instance();

        $ci->db->select('*');
        $ci->db->from('top_menu');
        $ci->db->order_by('menu_name');
        $query = $ci->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $menu[] = array(
                                'id' => $row["id"],
                                'label' => $row["menu_name"]
                            );
        }
        return json_encode($menu);
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(get_data());
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        function split( val ) 
        {
            return val.split( /,\s*/ );
        }
        function extractLast( term ) 
        {
            return split( term ).pop();
        }
        $( "#tags" )
        .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.getJSON( "<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/search", {
                    term: extractLast( request.term )
                }, response );
            },
            search: function() {
                var term = extractLast( this.value );
                if ( term.length < 1 ) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            focus: function() {
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                terms.pop();
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control1" id="tags" name="tags"/>
</div>
```

controller: **user.php**

```
public function search()
{
    $this->load->view('user/search_json');
}
```

In this code, I have created a json format file (i.e. search_json.php) and I want to implement it inside index.php. search_json.php file works perfectly, data is in proper format, but when I write something inside the tags input field it shows nothing. So, how can I fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you got some errors on debugger console ?

Comment: no error are showing @MathieuDormeval

Comment: Is your `user/search_json` is beeing called ?

Comment: No, @MathieuDormeval nothing happen. But if I create a seperate file then its work

Comment: You'll probably have to set headers. CodeIgniter will server the JSON as `text/html`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/search` can, and should be used like `<?php echo base_url('user/search'); ?>`. (I mostly do `<?= base_url().'user/search'; ?>` though :) Funny to see I'm not the only one using it 'wrong'...

If I have ajax controllers I tend to set the output like this:

```
$this
    ->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode($return)); // Where $return is an array
```

So in your case I guess you should load the json php file as a partial and set the output to the partial contents:

```
public function search() {
    $return = $this->load->view('user/search_json', '', true);
    $this
        ->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output($return);
}
```